# Change height of whole page with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the height of the whole page with bootstrap, it have img and text. How can I do that and all the elements change their size at once?

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
<body style="min-height:950px;height:auto !important">
```

Example 2 :

- Mouse Right Click "The item checks"
- Find the class in the style file change it.